# proof - geometric proof of integration by parts

Tags: integration, geometry

I was trying to prove integration by parts using 3D geometry.

$$ \int f(x) g(x) dx = f(x) \int g(x)dx - \int (\int g(x) dx) df$$

[image]

Here, ABCDEFGH is a cuboid. GL is $f(x + dx) - f(x)$ and EI is $g(x + dx) - g(x)$.
So, I am trying to equate the volume of LHS and RHS. Also, I think the small part to the bottom right will be ignored as it is ignored in the product rule.

But, I am not able to identify exactly which shapes represent which part.

Please help.
Thanks.

P. S. I've seen the 2D proof but want to try this 3D proof.

Comment: I am confused by the question. Why is a 1D integral a volume? Where is the cuboid defined? What are GL and EI? Do you have a figure? Or a link to the 2D proof?

Comment: @Andrei The figure is in the question itself.